# wrong ISO returned from CTCarrier on iPhone for certain countries

Tags: iphone, iso

This is not a question but rather a note for other developers who might be using CTCarrier.

I have been developing an app which requires reading the iso of the SIM card to determine the country the app is being used in (at least the SIM country). The doc mentions the following about the isoCountryCode property:

> ### This property uses the ISO 3166-1 country code representation.

From my tests and deployment however it appears that the returned iso is not the standard ISO 3166-1 for several countries (not sure if this is Apple's mistake of the carrier who stored  the info in the SIM)! So i had to do a translational phase to resolve the incorrect ISO's. The following is the list i have got to so far (will keep updating it once i get new incorrect iso's):

```
Country:             ISO I get        Expected ISO
----------           ----------       -------------
UK                      uk                 gb     
Japan                   ja                 jp
```

Cheers
AF

Answer (score 1):

UK was reserved by the the United Kingdom (and is an an appendix to the standard) so that's a grey area ;)

JA should be Jamacia - why do you expect this to be Japan?

Info from here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Comment: I am not expecting it to be Japan, a user in Japan with a Japanese SIM reported to me that the app on his iphone returned ja not jp! So i am just sharing this here as it could be useful. I will report all findings from different users abroad if i find anything elase

Comment: Btw the ISO for Jamaica is JM now JA